# react-native on android getting error like "TypeError: Network request failed"

Tags: android, react-native

export function rtiUpdate(data, callback) {`enter code here`
        console.log("dimuuuu");
        console.log(data);`enter code here`
      if(data.asking == "AskingMoreYes"){
      const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('asking', data.asking);
        formData.append('rti_id', data.rti_id);
        // formData.append('test', "test one");
          return dispatch => {
              dispatch({ type: RTIUPDATE});
              fetch(URL + '/rti-request/update-status',{
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: {
                      'Authorization': global.TOKEN_TYPE + ' ' + global.TOKEN,
                      "Accept": "application/json",
                      "Content-Type": "application/json"
                  },
                  body: formData,
              })
                  .then(response => {
                      console.log(response)
                      if (!response.ok) {
                          callback(false);
                          throw new Error(response.status);
                      }
                      else {
                          return response.json();
                      }
                  })
                  .then(responseJson => {
                      console.log('rtiUpdate - ', responseJson);
                      dispatch({ type: RTIUPDATE_SUCCESS, data: responseJson });
                      callback(true);
                  })
                  .catch(err => {
                      console.log('rtiUpdate Err- ', err);
                      dispatch({ type: RTIUPDATE_FAILD });
                      callback(false);
                  });
          };
      }else{
      const formData2 = new FormData();

```
    formData2.append('rti_payment_file', data.rti_payment_file);
    formData2.append('rti_id', data.rti_id);
      return dispatch => {
          dispatch({ type: RTIUPDATE});
          fetch(URL + '/rti-request/update-status',{
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                  'Authorization': global.TOKEN_TYPE + ' ' + global.TOKEN,
                  "Accept": "application/json",
                  "Content-Type": "application/json"
              },
              body: formData2,
          })
              .then(response => {
                  console.log(response)
                  if (!response.ok) {
                      callback(false);
                      throw new Error(response.status);
                  }
                  else {
                      return response.json();
                  }
              })
              .then(responseJson => {
                  console.log('rtiUpdate - ', responseJson);
                  dispatch({ type: RTIUPDATE_SUCCESS, data: responseJson });
                  callback(true);
              })
              .catch(err => {
                  console.log('rtiUpdate Err- ', err);
                  dispatch({ type: RTIUPDATE_FAILD });
                  callback(false);
              });
      };
  }
}
```